# how to Redirect the page in Add to cart button click

Tags: addtocart

I want to redirect the page when i am clicking add to cart button

For ex :

> **product_Name** : Product1
>
> **Redirect_url** : www.somedomain.com...\Product1 (other site url not mine)
>
> **product_Name** : Product2
>
> **Redirect_url** : www.somedomain.com...\Product2 (other site url not mine)

when I am clicking **add to cart** button just to **redirect** `www.somedomain.com\...\Product1` .. `\product`... not to redirect `checkout/cart/`page

Answer (score 2):

There is an option on the add to cart from to submit `submit_route_data` which will override the standard add to cart url used in Magento.

```
public function getSubmitUrl($product, $additional = array())
{
    $submitRouteData = $this->getData('submit_route_data');
    if ($submitRouteData) {
        $route = $submitRouteData['route'];
        $params = isset($submitRouteData['params']) ? $submitRouteData['params'] : array();
        $submitUrl = $this->getUrl($route, array_merge($params, $additional));
    } else {
        $submitUrl = $this->getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional);
    }
    return $submitUrl;
}
```

I have not used this myself but this should work at least for internal urls. An example can be found at `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Configure.php` in the function `_prepareLayout`.

For external urls you may need to work with the event `controller_action_(pre|post)dispatch_{{fullActionName}}` here you should be able to catch the pre dispatch for the add to cart action and then simply redirect the user when the product being added matches a certain product.

Comment: Thank You sir for your idea i will try... thanks a lot @DavidManners

Answer (score 1):

Go to app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

```
protected function _goBack()
    {
        $returnUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('return_url');
        if ($returnUrl) {

            if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($returnUrl)) {
                throw new Mage_Exception('External urls redirect to "' . $returnUrl . '" denied!');
            }

            $this->_getSession()->getMessages(true);
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);
        } elseif (!Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/cart/redirect_to_cart')
            && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('in_cart')
            && $backUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl()
        ) {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl);
        } else {
            if (($this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'add') && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('in_cart')) {
                $this->_getSession()->setContinueShoppingUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());
            }
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');//enter url to redirect page
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update from

```
System -> Configuration -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart -> Set After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart = Yes
```

Check below screenshot.

[image]